# Python-SocketIO on Windows: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io

I'm in the process of writing a minimal websocket server with Python 3. I am using `flask`, `socketio`, and `eventlet` per the instructions on the latest docs. The problem is that when the webpage with the socket connection is reloaded, the server throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenpool.py", line 88, in _spawn_n_impl
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 734, in process_request
    proto.__init__(sock, address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 686, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 651, in finish
    greenio.shutdown_safe(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 479, in shutdown_safe
    return sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I took a look at the source, and it seems like `shutdown_safe` is supposed to just catch any exceptions while shutting down a connection. In short, it seems like the author of this part of the library didn't foresee Windows throwing an OSError on shutdown.

Although this is a benign issue, I was wondering if there are any existing fixes/tweaks, and if not, whether I should submit this to the `python-socketio` GitHub issues list.